# I keep getting an Expected RBRACE error in css

Tags: css

I was trying to use this code as a theme in Discord but I get errors on all lines. It says `Expected RBRACE at line x col x`. It also says that `Rule is empty`.

```
:root {
    --white: white;
    --black: black;
    --sidebarServers: #353945;
    --sidebarChannels: #383C4a;
    --text: #7a8b94;
    --textLowContrast: #bbbcbd;
    --textDark: #d3dae3;
    --textDarkLowContrast: #767e83;
    --textAccent: white;
    --bgContent: #f5f6f7;
    --bgContentDark: #404552;
    --bgAccent: #5294e2;
    --bgInput: #fff;
    --bgInputDark: #1c212b;
    --bgChatInput: #e6e7e8;
    --bgChatInputDark: #383C4a;
    --bgToolbar: #353945;
    --bgMenu: #fff;
    --bgMenuDark: #383c4a;
    --bgDarker: #2d323d;
    --bgDarkest: #262a33;
    --buttonContent: #e6e7e8;
    --buttonContentDark: #4c5262;
    --buttonDarker: #4b5164;
    --buttonToolbar: #474d5d;
    --buttonAccent: #88b9f2;
    --mentionedDark: rgba(136,185,242,0.15);
    --online: #5294e2;
    --away: #e6b807;
    --busy: #ea0d0b;
    --dividerContent: #383C4a;
    --dividerChannel: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    --time: 0.1s;
}
```

Comment: Is this the complete code or are there some parts missing?

Comment: This is the part of the code with the errors

Comment: Then post the whole code please.